# CSV file to an array to a table? (Python 3.10.4)

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, prettytable

I'm new to Python and doing some project based learning.
I have a CSV file that I've put into an array but I'd like present it in PrettyTable

Here's what I have so far:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('destiny.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=";"))

data = np.array(data)
```

Output is this:

```
 ['Loud Lullaby,Aggressive,Moon,Kinetic,120,Legendary,hand_cannon']
 ['Pribina-D,Aggressive,Gunsmith,Kinetic,120,Legendary,hand_cannon']
 ['True Prophecy,Aggressive,World,Kinetic,120,Legendary,hand_cannon']
 ['Igneous Hammer,Aggressive,Trials,Solar,120,Legendary,hand_cannon']
```

But I'd like to get it into this:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

myTable = PrettyTable(['Gun Name', 'Archetype', 'Source', 'Element', 'Rounds Per Minute', 'Rarity', 'Weapon Type'])

myTable.add_row(['Loud Lullaby', 'Aggressive', 'Moon', 'Kinetic', '120', 'Legendary', 'Hand Cannon'])
myTable.add_row(["Pribina-D", "Aggressive", "Gunsmith", "Kinetic", "120", "Legendary", "Hand Cannon"])
myTable.add_row(["True Prophecy", "Aggressive", "World", "Kinetic", "120", "Legendary", "Hand Cannon"])
myTable.add_row(["Igneous Hammer", "Aggressive", "Trials", "Solar", "120", "Legendary", "Hand Cannon"])
```

So it can look like this:

```
 Gun Name            |  Archetype   |     Source    | Element | Rounds Per Minute |   Rarity  | Weapon Type |
+---------------------------------+--------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+
|           Loud Lullaby          |  Aggressive  |      Moon     | Kinetic |        120        | Legendary | Hand Cannon |
|            Pribina-D            |  Aggressive  |    Gunsmith   | Kinetic |        120        | Legendary | Hand Cannon |
|          True Prophecy          |  Aggressive  |     World     | Kinetic |        120        | Legendary | Hand Cannon |
|          Igneous Hammer         |  Aggressive  |     Trials    |  Solar  |        120        | Legendary | Hand Cannon |
```

Thoughts on the best way to get the data set incorporated into the table without having to copy and paste every line into myTable.add_row? Because there's hundreds of lines...

[Credit to vishwasrao99 at Kaggle for this CSV file]

Answer (score 0):

I just combined your two pieces of script:

```py
import csv
import numpy as np
from prettytable import PrettyTable

with open('destiny.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=";"))

data = np.array(data)

columns = ['Gun Name', 'Archetype', 'Source', 'Element', 'Rounds Per Minute', 'Rarity', 'Weapon Type']
myTable = PrettyTable(columns)

for row in data:
    list = row[0].split(",")
    myTable.add_row(list)

print(myTable)
```

Note that I used split(",") to split the strings you get in your numpy array at every comma, creating identical lists as what you feed in manually in your example.

Comment: Thank you! It just worked! I had errors but I fixed them!

Comment: Well, that's good. Also remember to accept the answer so the question can be closed and won't hang around.